serverless-webpack giving error while deploying on lambda
"serverless-webpack": "^5.13.0"
Error:
fs.readFileAsync is not a function
TypeError: fs.readFileAsync is not a function
    at ServerlessWebpack.getFileContentAndStat (/Users/new/Desktop/projects/analytics-migration/node_modules/serverless-webpack/lib/packageModules.js:93:8)
    at /Users/new/Desktop/projects/analytics-migration/node_modules/serverless-webpack/lib/packageModules.js:57:74
    at arrayMap (/Users/new/Desktop/projects/analytics-migration/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:653:23)
    at Function.map (/Users/new/Desktop/projects/analytics-migration/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9622:14)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/Users/new/Desktop/projects/analytics-migration/node_modules/serverless-webpack/lib/packageModules.js:57:23)
    at WriteStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at WriteStream.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at WriteStream.stream.emit (node:internal/fs/streams:61:9)
    at file:///Users/new/.serverless/releases/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:335:14
    at file:///Users/new/.serverless/releases/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:362:16
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:189:23


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I got this error too when tried to upgrade  serverless v3 --> v4. Still trying to figure out the reason..

I created a bug issue to serverless-webpack: https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack/issues/1912
